# python: reportlab: excel table did not fit with size

Tags: python, reportlab

I try to read and print an Exceltable (with text, umlauten $%°() ). I make the read in with xlrd and print it with reportlab. The result is bad. My table did not fit with the sitze, the text did not have line breaks for each column and therefore column width is to wide. Is there a way to force reportlab to do this?
Here is my code:

```
>import xlrd
>wb = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls", 
>encoding_override="UTF-8")#"iso-8859-1")
>wb.sheet_names()
>sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
>
>rows = []
>for row_number in xrange(sh.nrows):
>     rows.append(sh.row_values(row_number))
>
>data=[row for row in rows]
>
>
>from reportlab.lib import colors
>from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
>from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph
>from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
>from reportlab.lib.units import inch
>from reportlab.platypus.paragraph.cleanBlockQuotedText
>styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
>doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table.pdf", pagesize=letter)
>
>elements = []
>
>t=Table(data)
>elements.append(t)
>doc.build(elements)
```

Did somebody see my mistake? Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the data - why not print it as formatted in Excel?

Comment: I will put it in Latex. Here in the example one part is missing. I make 2 thins:
1. 2 lines
2. fonts and size of the letters should be fit with latex